# Is there an universal way to access SmartWatch's sensors from Android App?

Tags: android, bluetooth, smartphone, sony-smartwatch

I need to create an app that can access to the Sensors of Smartwatch or FitWatch, regardless of what is the brand of that werable. I need to export data (like heart rate, blood oxygenation ecc.) from any werable device to the smartphone where the app is installed (with bluetooth connection).
Is there an universal way to do this? How does data sharing work from werables to phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, every manufacturer cooks its own soup here. But many manufacturers also share their data via the [Google Fit API](https://developers.google.com/fit).